# Из JQuery в чистый JS

Tags: jquery, javascript

JQuery:

```
 var body_w = $('body').width();
 if(body_w <= 1100) {
  $('#start, #header, #info, #info .telephone_free,').addClass('mini');
 }
```

Как написать тоже самое, только на чистом JS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if( document.body.offsetWidth <= 1100 ){
  var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('#start, #header, #info, #info .telephone_free');
  [].forEach.call(nodeList, function (el){
       el.classList.add("mini");
  });
}
```

Comment: @RubaXa, ого! Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @RubaXa, [].forEach.call - зачем создавать новый массив, когда можно вызвать forEach у прототипа?

Comment: @Lucky, можно даже вынести этот метод в отдельную переменную, но что-то мне подсказывает, что это разовая операция и игра не стоит свеч.